# Заставить работать скрипт ежесекундно

Tags: ajax, javascript

Доброго.

Есть переменная в сессии у пользователя, охота значение этой переменной выводить на экран с обновлением 1 раз в секунду (ну или 1 раз в 2 секунды). Сразу ассоциация - AJAX.

```
<!--мой многострадальный скрипт-->
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                function update(){
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"how_session_count_sheep.php",
                            type:"POST",
                            cache:true,
                            data: "id=<? echo ''.$_SESSION['count_sheep'].''; ?>"),
                            success: function(html){
                                $("#count_sheep_status").html(html);
                            }
                        })
                }
                update();
            });
    </script>
```

Собственно, при загрузке страницы - без проблем. А вот как сделать, чтобы функция срабатывала каждую секунду, не понимаю. Подскажите?

Comment: используйте [setTimeout](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout), который будет запускать Ваш скрипт через указанное время. Так как он перезапускает один раз, то в фунции success его нужно будет каждый раз выставлять. Также, нужно будет выставить в обработчике ошибок.

Comment: @KoVadim setTimeout выполняет скрипт через какой-то промежуток времени. В данном случае нужен setInerval, как в ответе ниже.

Comment: Кстати, к слову, слать запросы каждую секунду - просто капец какая плохая идея :)

Comment: Вот потому что слать запросы постоянно - плохая идея, я и рекомендую setTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
function update(){
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"how_session_count_sheep.php",
                            type:"POST",
                            cache:true,
                            data: "id=<? echo ''.$_SESSION['count_sheep'].''; ?>"),
                            success: function(html){
                                $("#count_sheep_status").html(html);
                            }
                        })
                }
                update();
},1000)
```

Comment: Ваш вариант с setInterval плохой. У него есть один существенный недостаток. Представьте себе, что сеть чуть затормозилась.

Comment: Но в варианте с таймаутом также есть один существенный недостаток, представьте, что вылетел интернет. В итоге в success не выполнилось, код работу остановил и для продолжения нам необходимо обновляться.

Comment: Я писал выше, что в обработчике ошибок запроса также нужно добавить код, который разрулит ошибку красиво. Я бы просто выводил сообщение "Нет интернета, попробовать ещё раз?" и по клику выставлял таймер. Но большинство пользователей просто перезагрузит страницу.