# Отправка AJAX'ом нескольких переменных вместо одной

Tags: ajax, javascript

Доброго.

```
// внутри AJAX есть строка, которая передает POST'ом данные
//строка:
data: "id=5",

//на странице, получаем POST в виде массива
['id'] => 5
```

Собственно, как можно модернизировать отправку, чтобы можно было посылать несколько значений? Сам я, естественно, пробовал, но получал ошибки. Есть еще вариант - массив, но это, по сути, одна переменная. Хотелось получить в POST, что-то в роде:

```
['id'] => 5
['title'] => убейте меня
['name'] => иван
```

p.s. [мой многострадальный скрипт, для полного понимания вопроса выше, хотя его и так все видели )](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/369977/javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не формируйте гет-пост строки вручную. Никогда.

```
data: {
    id: 5,
    title: 'supertitle',
    name: 'bark bark',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В параметрах AJAX (у тебя конкретно POST), передавай data вот так:

```
data: {id: "5", title: "убейте меня", name: "иван"}
```

Comment: Акцепт влепляю @Etki, т.к. он ответил первым. Спасибо, по коду все получилось.